# How to remove select <DEBUG log> in output intellij idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, console

Intellij hides some text in "select" and prints <"DEBUG log"> in output console.

I'm not sure but I use special symbol '\u2003' and that's can be trigger. When I replace it with normal space (' '), there's no problem.

[image: Screenshot of IDE]

I want there was no  and "selects" in output because it ruins format output but also I need to use '\u2003' though I can't remove it.

Comment: It doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hardcoded folding for the `EM SPACE` (`u2003`) character and it's not possible to control this folding at the moment. I've [created an issue in YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-222222), feel free to vote.

See [com.intellij.testFramework.FailedTestDebugLogConsoleFolding](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/testFramework/src/com/intellij/testFramework/FailedTestDebugLogConsoleFolding.java#L27) and [com.intellij.testFramework.TestLoggerFactory#FAILED_TEST_DEBUG_OUTPUT_MARKER](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/testFramework/src/com/intellij/testFramework/TestLoggerFactory.java#L148).